# How to export BQ tables to GCS in JSON format without change in encoding

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I exported a BQ table to GCS in JSON format using python. The export was successful, however, when I download the JSON files from GCS, I noticed that special caracters have changed. For example,

```
Shirt & Trouser Presses
```

in BQ has changed to

```
Shirt \u0026 Trouser Presses
```

in GCS.

Is there a way to to ensure that the encoding does not change while exporting from BQ to GCS in JSON format?

Here is the code snippet I use:

```
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(BQ_PROJECT, dataset_id)
        client = bigquery.Client(project=BQ_PROJECT)
        tables = client.list_tables(dataset_id)
        job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
        job_config.destination_format = bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
        for table in tables:
            if table.table_type == "TABLE":
                table_id = table.table_id
                destination_blob = table_id
                table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
                destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(BUCKET, destination_blob)
    
                extract_job = client.extract_table(
                    table_ref,
                    destination_uri,
                    job_config=job_config,
                    # Location must match that of the source table.
                    location="EU",
                )  # API request
                extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

Comment: My guess is that the data was imported with that encoding, The data probably was from an HTML form that was incorrectly imported into BigQuery.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't think so , because when i export it as CSV from BQ to GCS, it has the right encoding (when I downloaded it from GCS later)

Comment: CSV is not conclusive. Let's not guess. Write code that reads the column/row with the problem data. Tip: In Python, you can read the string JSON and then write it back out as a string. The embedded Unicode will be converted to normal characters provided you use `encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for your follow up. You are right, when I read the files from GCS with pandas, I get the right encoding. So "Shirt \u0026 Trouser Presses" will be read as  "Shirt & Trouser Presses" using pandas.

Comment: @JohnHanley it is one of my first staskoverflow posts, how can i flag your answer as correct? thanks for help

Comment: I only posted a comment. Go ahead and post your own answer with the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @johnHanley, I figured out that when I read data from GCS using pandas I get the right encoding back. So `"Shirt \u0026 Trouser Presses"` will be read as `"Shirt & Trouser Presses"` using pandas. Hence the problem is solved